# Duda con Laravel Query Builder

Tags: sql, laravel

Me podrian ayudar, quiero hacer este Query en laravel pero simplemente no encuentro como

```
SELECT CONTRATO
,CASE WHEN RAZONSOCIAL IS NULL OR RAZONSOCIAL='' THEN ISNULL(PATERNO,'') +' '+ ISNULL(MATERNO,'') +' '+ ISNULL(NOMBRES,'') ELSE RAZONSOCIAL END AS NOMBRE
,CADENAUNICA,CLAVERASTREO,FECHAASIENTO,IDGARANTIA, RutaGuardadoPDF, RutaGuardadoXML
FROM DEUDORES AS D
LEFT JOIN RELACIONES AS R ON D.RUGID=R.RUGID
WHERE CONTRATO='A1412015'
AND D.AcreedorId IN
(SELECT ACREEDORID FROM [MasterCLI].[dbo].[Rrug] WHERE FIDEICOMISOID=5)
```

Llevo esto, pero en realidad no se si este bien

```
$AcreedorFide = \DB::connection('sqlsrv')->table('Rrug')
        ->select('AcreedorID')
        ->where('Fideicomiso', $fideicomiso)
        ->get();

        $BoletaRUG = \DB::connection('RUG')->table('Deudores')
        ->select('Contrato','CadenaUnica','ClaveRastreo','FechaAsiento','IdGarantia', 'RutaGuardadoPDF', 'RutaGuardadoXML')
        ->select(DB::raw('CASE WHEN RAZONSOCIAL IS NULL'  ))
        ->leftJoin('Relaciones','Deudores.RugId', '=', 'Relaciones.RugId')
        ->where('Contrato', $Contrato)
        ->wherein('Acreedorid', $AcreedorFide)
        ->get();
```

Comment: No tengo ni idea de Laravel, pero tal vez te ayude simplificar un poco la expresión del nombre a `ISNULL( NULLIF(RAZONSOCIAL, ''), ISNULL(PATERNO + ' ','')+ ISNULL(MATERNO + ' ','')+ ISNULL(NOMBRES,'')) AS NOMBRE`

Comment: Puedes dar más datos acerca del error o el resultado que estas obteniendo para poder apoyarte.

Comment: EL error me esta dando cuando intento convertir a Laravel esta parte "CASE WHEN RAZONSOCIAL IS NULL OR RAZONSOCIAL='' THEN ISNULL(PATERNO,'') +' '+ ISNULL(MATERNO,'') +' '+ ISNULL(NOMBRES,'') ELSE RAZONSOCIAL END AS NOMBRE"

Comment: Para ayudarte bien deberías indicar la versión de Laravel que estas usando (para por ejemplo saber si puedes usar when o no) así como si es una tabla que consultes habitualmente (para crear o no el modelo)